# Eloqua API "EmailTestDeployment" report shows as live send

Tags: oracle, eloqua

I'm using the REST API 2.0 for sending quick tests but they're coming through as 'live' sends in the reports. Surely there's a way for it show up as a test, right? I feel like I'm missing something simple but not sure what it is. Here's the object I'm passing in the request body:

```
{
   "type": "EmailTestDeployment",
   "name": "REST Test 01",
   "contactId": selectedContact[0].id,
   "sendFromUserId": null,
   "email": {
      "type": "Email",
      "id": email.id,
      "name": email.name
   },
   "sendOptions": {
      "allowResend": "true",
      "allowSendToUnsubscribe": "true"
   }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sending a test email is only available through the user interface. I would recommend creating a test copy of the email for API test sends so it does not muddle your reporting as much.